# Where are the application containers of Spring Cloud Data Flow in a docker compose deployment?

Tags: docker, spring-cloud-dataflow

I followed the Spring Cloud Dataflow docs at https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/ and deployed everything using docker-compose.

Everything went fine and I can see the example stream working.

One thing I don't understand: After deploying the stream I expected to see a container for every application if i do a `docker ps`, but that is not the case. If the applications are not deployed as individual containers how are they executed?

Output of `docker ps`:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                            COMMAND                   CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                          NAMES
40bb0007bfd0   springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.9.1   "bin/sh -c '\n   apt-…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:9393->9393/tcp                                         dataflow-server
450a11a2b25c   springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.8.1    "bin/sh -c '\n   apt-…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:7577->7577/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20000-20195->20000-20195/tcp   skipper
e0773f0f9d33   confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.2                      "/etc/confluent/dock…"    3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   9092/tcp                                                       dataflow-kafka
2d1aeb3435e2   mysql:5.7.25                                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"    3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                            dataflow-mysql
cd3658fc93a4   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.2                  "/etc/confluent/dock…"    3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp                                   dataflow-kafka-zookeeper
```

Comment: Did you read https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/#docker-stream--task-applications?

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to @jonrsharpe I found the processes inside skipper:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                            COMMAND                   CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                          NAMES
40bb0007bfd0   springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.9.1   "bin/sh -c '\n   apt-…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:9393->9393/tcp                                         dataflow-server
450a11a2b25c   springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.8.1    "bin/sh -c '\n   apt-…"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:7577->7577/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20000-20195->20000-20195/tcp   skipper
e0773f0f9d33   confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.5.2                      "/etc/confluent/dock…"    3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   9092/tcp                                                       dataflow-kafka
2d1aeb3435e2   mysql:5.7.25                                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"    3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                            dataflow-mysql
cd3658fc93a4   confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.5.2                  "/etc/confluent/dock…"    3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp                                   dataflow-kafka-zookeeper

$ docker exec -it 450a11a2b25c /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                 
root@450a11a2b25c:/# ps -aux                                                                                                                                                                                             
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND                                                                                                                                                 
root         1  0.0  0.0   4640     0 ?        Ss   05:55   0:00 bin/sh -c     apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y wget &&    wget --no-check-certificate -P /tmp/ https://raw.githubusercontent
root       209  0.8 16.3 1149340 332864 ?      Sl   05:56   1:47 java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher                                                                                                        
root       957  1.1  9.8 3106508 201096 ?      Sl   08:57   0:24 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jre/bin/java -jar /root/.m2/repository/io/spring/dataflow/sample/usage-detail-sender-kafka/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/us
root       981  1.4 11.9 3100332 242944 ?      Sl   08:57   0:31 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jre/bin/java -jar /root/.m2/repository/io/spring/dataflow/sample/usage-cost-logger-kafka/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/usag
root      1003  1.5 12.3 3101360 252020 ?      Sl   08:57   0:34 /layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jre/bin/java -jar /root/.m2/repository/io/spring/dataflow/sample/usage-cost-processor-kafka/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/u
root      1104  1.0  0.1  18516  3244 pts/0    Ss   09:34   0:00 /bin/bash                                                                                                                                               
root      1114  0.0  0.1  34416  2740 pts/0    R+   09:34   0:00 ps -aux                                                                                                                                                 
root@450a11a2b25c:/#
```